# There is an UI issue for the ranking div when a user crossed 200 reputation

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, reputation-leagues

When a user just crossed 200, or 200+ reputation, the ranked div (i.e., top 10% overall) is trying to display. But rank calculation can be done on end of the UTC day. So instead of the ranking div, there is a blue colored hyphen is visible to users, it may be the initial loader for the ranking div.

I saw this UI issue previously too for the same scenario. Can this be fixed?

> [image: 200+ rep]

Comment: Cross-site post on MSO: [Blue minus sign besides my name](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397865/4642212).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been fixed.

The issue existed due to the way that we loaded the league status for a user - if it is in cache then it is loaded in to the view on the server-side, otherwise it is loaded in a client-side call (so as not to hold up the page load). For cases where a user did not yet have any league ranking, the client-side would not return anything. This is fine, but it would end up leaving an empty `div` that had the classes needed to style the results properly, including horizontal padding and a `1px border`, which resulted in that little line.

This has been fixed so that in the case where nothing is loaded on the server side (not yet cached), the box is hidden, and the box is only revealed if the client-side call returns something to show.

---

> Enough rep for leagues
> but nothing calculated
> no more empty box