# Strange blue line in profile page of relatively new staff member

Tags: bug, profile-page, stack-exchange-team, rankings

The [profile page of this staff member](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/440650/peter-kay) has a strange blue line next to the Staff indicator:

[image]

Looking at the HTML source, I presume this is because they're not ranked yet:

[image]

This only seems to happen for staff members, not for other users.

Tested in the latest Safari and Firefox on macOS Catalina.

Comment: Reproduced on chrome on android

Comment: If this related/similar bug gets resolved, is your report status-completed in that case as well ? [There is an UI issue for the ranking div when a user crossed 200 reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332691/there-is-an-ui-issue-for-the-ranking-div-when-a-user-crossed-200-reputation)