# Line next to username on profile

Tags: discussion, profile-page, display-names

My [Retrocomputing profile](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/6953/pacoverflow?tab=profile) shows a short line next to my username:

[image]

I thought it might be like a placeholder for the "top x%" that's next to my profile on other sites where I have more rep, such as [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/202205/pacoverflow?tab=profile):

[image]

But there are other sites where I have low rep and there's no line next to my username, like on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/users/567783/pacoverflow?tab=profile):

[image]

So why does a line appear next to my username on my Retrocomputing profile?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [There is an UI issue for the ranking div when a user crossed 200 reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332691/there-is-an-ui-issue-for-the-ranking-div-when-a-user-crossed-200-reputation)

Comment: TL;DR: because you just crossed 200 today, and the league scores weren't yet calculated.