# Empty span showing in profile page

Tags: bug, design

If nothing to show on leagues changes, please hide that span.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [There is an UI issue for the ranking div when a user crossed 200 reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332691/there-is-an-ui-issue-for-the-ranking-div-when-a-user-crossed-200-reputation) - He gained [230 reputation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRQNt.png) today, up from 101.